# Code visibility in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Today I checked a source code of one of the websites done in Angular and I wondered if it is a good practice to display bits like below available for everyone to see.

```
ul class="nav-account desktop-only" ng-show="!User.isAuthenticated" ng-cloak
```

I understand it is safe in terms of back-end because I cannot set these parameters but I just wondered if this is a good practice or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative. You can go and also see all the code for the controllers, directives and provides. Probably it is minified but a good it will make that readable again.

This is always anywhere the case if you give software to your client – you always do.

And even if you managed to obfuscate the code in a way nobody can ever read it again, the user could use a tool to simply log all request to the server made from his computer.

You cannot protect against your users. The only way to protect your service is to write a stable and secure API. (validate everything, send secure authentication tokens, protect against brute force)

---

Just as an example:

[image]

Apple does not try to hide their Angular directives. They are not even minified.

Answer (score 2):

The client side is never secure, and can never be trusted. Validations on the client side are highly recommended, while the server side **MUST** be validated and secured.

So examples like these are generally "ok" if any actions sent to the server are authorized anyway. It will just fail.